# Porque no puedo mostrar un Fragment desde otro Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

tengo creado un menú horizontal, y uno de los Fragment que componen el menú me muestra un botón, que al pulsarlo tendría que mostrar otro Fragment, pero no se muestra, no muestra ningún error, simplemente no llega a mostrarse.

Este es el Fragment donde tengo puesto el botón para que se muestre el otro Fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 1", R.drawable.home_icon, true);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Boton", R.drawable.round_account);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Esquema", R.drawable.notifications);

    horizontal_menu.showItems();//hacemos visible los items del menu

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //cambiamos el elemento seleccionado del menu a la posicion actual del viewpager
            horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    //implementamos la interface para caputar los clic en el menu
    horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    });
}


private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    //public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Menu1();
            case 1:
                return new Boton();
            case 2:
                return new Esquema();
            default:
                return new Menu1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment **Boton.java**

```
public class Boton extends Fragment {

private Button verEsquema;

public Boton() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView  = inflater.inflate( R.layout.boton, container, false );

    verEsquema = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_boton1);

    verEsquema.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment nuevoFragmento = new Esquema();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, nuevoFragmento);
             transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), nuevoFragmento);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

**boton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_boton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Boton 1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment **Esquema.java**

```
public class Esquema extends Fragment {

WebView mWebView;

public Esquema() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.esquema, container, false );

    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById( R.id.webView_esquema);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom( WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR );
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/esquema.html");

    return view;
}
}
```

**esquema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_esquema"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenulibrary.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
    app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
    app:icon_height="50dp"
    app:icon_width="50dp"
    app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
    app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

¿Me podríais decir que estoy haciendo mal y porque no se muestra?

Gracias.

Comment: Mira tu código para cambiar el fragment se ve bien, intenta remplazar esto
R.id.frame_container 
por esto 
((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()

Comment: Si es un viewpager tendrias que cambia la vista del childfragment, me encantaria que me mostrar tus activity donde donde poblas el viewpager pero seria algo asi
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.pcontainer_2, nuevoFragmento)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit()

suponiendo que R.id.pcontainer_2 es el id de tu layout de page container numero 2

Comment: Hola @Darkeniel el menu horizontal lo tengo en el MainActivity, he puesto una imagen arriba, tambien he cambiado el codigo que dices, mira a ve si es asi como dices, porque no me muestra el Fragment pero por lo menos algo hace, el boton desaparece pero no me muestra el fragmen, ya no se si es por como esta el activity_main.xml he puesto el codido arriba.

Comment: Podrias poner un fodo color negro esquema.xml, para ver si esta cambiando y cambia a color negro

Comment: que raro, en **esquema.xml** he añadido **android:background="#000000"**, al pulsao en "Boton 1" sigue mostrando la pagina en blanco, pero lo raro es que si primero pulso en el menu "Esquema" ahi tengo puesto tambien el esquema y lo muestra, pero cuando pulso **Boton 1** que no muestra nada, despues voy al menu **Esquema** ahora ya no me muestra nada, mira mejor el video de lo que digo https://youtu.be/mV3TgsJndB8

Comment: Creo que tu video esta en privado porque no me aparece

Comment: mira ahora me falto dar en publicar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85944/discussion-between-darkeniel-and-socu).

Comment: desde de usar childFragment: viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

Comment: @armen dices de cambiar en el MainActivity.java, **viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);** por **viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));** si es así, se produce un error http://funkyimg.com/i/2NhDx.png